# Composite Collection Binding

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I try to use a composite collection (several collections will add later), but the elements simply do not appear on the screen. What is wrong?
Binding the collection to data control directly works just fine.
Here is my UserControl

```
<UserControl
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFTest.Views"
         xmlns:Model="clr-namespace:WPFTest.Model"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:WPFTest.ViewModels"
         x:Class="WPFTest.Views.PolygonEditorView"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Slider  Value="{Binding ScaleFactor}" Minimum="-4" Maximum="5" Interval="1" Orientation="Vertical" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" TickPlacement="Both"/>
    <ScrollViewer Width="1000" Height="1000" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.Column="1">
        <ItemsControl Name="ItemsControl" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <CompositeCollection >
                    <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Points}"/>
                </CompositeCollection>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Width="{Binding CanvasSize}" Height="{Binding CanvasSize}" Background="RoyalBlue"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                    <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                </Style>
            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="viewModels:EditorPoint" >
                    <Thumb Width="11" Height="11">
                        <Thumb.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Ellipse Width="11" Height="11" Fill="Gold"/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Thumb.Template>
                    </Thumb>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

and model:

```
 internal class PolygonEditorViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
    public BindableCollection<EditorPoint> Points { get; set; }

    private int _scaleFactor;

    public int ScaleFactor
    {
        get { return _scaleFactor; }
        set
        {
            _scaleFactor = value;
            foreach (var editorPoint in Points)
            {
                editorPoint.ScaleFactor = value;
            }
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CanvasSize);
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ScaleFactor);
            Points.Refresh();
        }
    }


    public double CanvasSize => 10000*Math.Pow(2, ScaleFactor);

    public PolygonEditorViewModel()
    {
        Points = new BindableCollection<EditorPoint>()
        {
            new EditorPoint() {Vertex = new Vertex() {X = 3500, Y = 3000}},
            new EditorPoint() {Vertex = new Vertex() {X = 6500, Y = 3000}},
            new EditorPoint() {Vertex = new Vertex() {X = 3500, Y = 7000}},
            new EditorPoint() {Vertex = new Vertex() {X = 6500, Y = 7000}},
            new EditorPoint() {Vertex = new Vertex() {X = 2500, Y = 5000}},
            new EditorPoint() {Vertex = new Vertex() {X = 7500, Y = 5000}}
        };
        ScaleFactor = -4;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you observe a binding error message in the Output Window in Visual Studio when you run the application?

Comment: No mistakes in the Output Window.

Comment: That's interesting. Why I try your approach, I get `System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=Points; DataItem=null; target element is 'CollectionContainer' (HashCode=25702951); target property is 'Collection' (type 'IEnumerable')` in the Output Window. I mean, when I run the applcation in debugger, not during build.